# Microcopy for "all people"/"no special group"

Tags: copywriting, dropdown

In the editor of our new app you can add people to the project and assign them (editors/reviewers). When adding them to the project you can filter all users on the account by predefined user-groups (design, development etc..)

So far so good.

The only system generated list item (and that's the one we are searching for an appropriate wording) is the one shown on default (Screenshot 1) that will display a list of all users added to the account below the dropdown, whereas the other list items displays all members of a predefined user group a customer has set up (Screenshot2: list item 1&2 user generated). We decided on that because it makes it easier for users who haven't created groups or added all co-workers to different groups.

**We've tried different microcopy variations: "No group", "General", "All people" and we also tried leaving it empty** Not really satisfied with our results here so maybe you've got some ideas that help us out?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is this text a label of? Are you looking for an alternative to 'people on this project'?

Comment: Yes it's not really clear what is being asked here, and it comes across as being very localised to just your application, meaning it's not going to benefit any other ux.se users other that yourself. The question has been closed for now, but you can still edit it to try to refine the question, but as it is it's too localised and unclear a question.

Comment: Sorry guys I refined the question. Hope it makes sense since I believe that this is is something that might be interesting for people handling user administration UIs and copy.

Answer (score 2):

"Everyone" is the way I'd phrase this personally.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just "All"

Keep it Simple (:

Answer (score 0):

What about "Select/assign people" if no groups are created and "select/assign a group" if so.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Guess you are referring to change the headline "People on this project" right? This would make sense too. But I'm really looking for the default list item copy which purpose is displaying all users on the account.